# Can I use microsoft.interop.outlook dll in azure app service?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am using Outlook meeting invitation for sending meeting using asp.net. Its working on Local machine, but When I deployed on Azure server, its not worked. Please suggest me way to implement Outlook meeting.

Comment: but interop office assemblies require the given applcation to ALSO be installed. So, interop alone will not suffice. You would have to install outlook, or Excel or whatever on the web server also.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Interop assemblies for applications, since they depend on the application that they are for to be installed.

If you want to do something with an M365/O365 account, please have a look at using [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

Comment: Do you have any code for open meeting invitation box.